# Show message to user if login details are wrong?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, authentication

How can I make it so if a user enters incorrect login details they get a error message? What I tried isn't working, when I press the button nothing happens

```
Private Sub Loginbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Loginbtn.Click
    'Allows user into app with specifc username & password (Login ID 1)
    If Usernamebtn.Text = "Business1" And Passwordbtn.Text = "qwerty1" Then
        MsgBox("You are Logged In!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Login")
        AppMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()


    Else

        'If no username or password field empty
        If Usernamebtn.Text = "" Or Passwordbtn.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Fill in the Username and Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")

            'If no username or password dosent match Login ID 
            If Usernamebtn.Text <> "Business1" AndAlso Passwordbtn.Text = "qwerty1" Then
                MsgBox("Dosen't Exist, Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
            Else
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to move your last If...Else...End If block outside of the If... block that checks for empty UserName or Password.

Comment: Also, have you tried setting Breakpoints and then stepping through the code examining control values as you go to understand why different code paths are taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
Private Sub Loginbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Loginbtn.Click
    'Allows user into app with specifc username & password (Login ID 1)
    If Usernamebtn.Text = "Business1" AndAlso Passwordbtn.Text = "qwerty1" Then
        MsgBox("You are Logged In!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Login")
        AppMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        'If username or password field empty
        If Usernamebtn.Text = "" OrElse Passwordbtn.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Fill in the Username and Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        Else
            MsgBox("User dosen't exist OR password incorrect, Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Something will happen.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!